# Is there any way to mapping point between 2 ecliptic curve?

Tags: cryptography, ecdsa

The ecliptic curve E1: y^2 = x^3+7 over F17 with the base point G is (15, 13)
and the second ecliptic curve E2: y^2 = x^3+7 over F31 with the same base point G is (15, 13).

My question is: is there any way to calculate the equivalent point of F31 based on F17?
For example: with 7G =  (10, 15) of curve F17, how to calculate 7G of F31 ? The result should be 7G =  (12, 14) on F31.

Below is all points of two curves:

#----Curve F17-------#

- 1G =  (15, 13)
- 2G =  (2, 10)
- 3G =  (8, 3)
- 4G =  (12, 1)
- 5G =  (6, 6)
- 6G =  (5, 8)
- 7G =  (10, 15)
- 8G =  (1, 12)
- 9G =  (3, 0)
- 10G =  (1, 5)
- 11G =  (10, 2)
- 12G =  (5, 9)
- 13G =  (6, 11)
- 14G =  (12, 16)
- 15G =  (8, 14)
- 16G =  (2, 7)
- 17G =  (15, 4)

#----Curve F31-------#

- 1G =  (15, 13)
- 2G =  (29, 17)
- 3G =  (1, 22)
- 4G =  (20, 19)
- 5G =  (21, 17)
- 6G =  (23, 23)
- 7G =  (12, 14)
- 8G =  (11, 27)
- 9G =  (25, 22)
- 10G =  (7, 19)
- 11G =  (27, 27)
- 12G =  (5, 9)
- 13G =  (0, 24)
- 14G =  (4, 12)
- 15G =  (22, 23)
- 16G =  (3, 13)
- 17G =  (13, 18)
- 18G =  (17, 23)
- 19G =  (24, 4)
- 20G =  (24, 27)
- 21G =  (17, 8)
- 22G =  (13, 13)
- 23G =  (3, 18)
- 24G =  (22, 8)
- 25G =  (4, 19)
- 26G =  (0, 7)
- 27G =  (5, 22)
- 28G =  (27, 4)
- 29G =  (7, 12)
- 30G =  (25, 9)
- 31G =  (11, 4)

Comment: This question would be a better match for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: The second basepoint seems wrong. One has isomorphic to Z/18 the other one Z/21. How do you expect this?

Comment: Thank you Jim. I moved my question to this url: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89362/is-there-any-way-to-mapping-point-between-2-ecliptic-curves but i don't know how to delete this question.